# Loops in Java after user inputs values

Tags: java, loops

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
              validNumbers = new int[200];
              Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File("validNumbers.txt"));
              int i = 0;  
              while(sc1.hasNextInt()) {
                  validNumbers[i++] = sc1.nextInt();                      
              }
          
              // Creating loop for what the user enters
              boolean newValidator = true;
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          
              while(newValidator) {
                  System.out.print("Enter the account number: ");
                  String num = scanner.nextLine();
              
                  // If found, the calculations will get displayed 
                  if(validator(num)) {
                      System.out.print("The calculated value to this account is: " + calculator(num));
                      newValidator = false;
                      System.out.println("\n" + "Would you like to enter another account number? (y/n)");
                      String ans = "";
                      ans = scanner.nextLine();
                  
                      // Needed the false, if not the code would keep asking to "Enter account number: "
                     if (ans.equals("y")) {
                         System.out.print("Enter the account number: ");
                         String num2 = scanner.nextLine();
                         System.out.print("The calculated value to this account is: " + calculator(num2));
                     } else if(ans.equals("n")) {
                         newValidator = false;
                         System.out.println("** Program Exit **");
                     }
                  }
              
                  // Wanted to add a loop for the user to decide if they want to continue iff wrong account is inputed
                  else {
                      System.out.println("Not valid account number" + "\n\n" + "Would you like to try again? (y/n)");
                      String ans = "";
                      ans = scanner.nextLine();
                      if(ans.equals("y")) {
                          newValidator = true;
                      }
                  
                      // How the program terminates if the user does not wish to continue
                      else if(ans.equals("n")) {
                          newValidator = false;
                          System.out.println("Not valid input, the program is now terminated!");
                      }
                  }
             }
        }
  }
```

**(Using Java) The code is doing the following:
1.) When the user enters a correct number it sees the number(in the file) and adds the digits
2.) When it is not in the file, it knows the number is not there and tells the user to try again and if the user doesn't want to, it ends the program.**
***** (Using Java) What the code is not doing:
1.) After they entered the right code, the program is to ask the user if they want to enter another account(with the adding of an account if so). Then this is where I have the problem, the loop is ending after this second go and I need it to keep asking if they want to enter another account number unit the user wants to exit.*****

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to have a nested question asking for another account number, the while loop itself will ask the user again when it repeats.

Simply ask the user if they want to enter another and then exit the loop if the don't.  The while loop drops out when "newValidator" is set to false:

```
boolean newValidator = true;
while(newValidator) {
    System.out.print("Enter the account number: ");
    String num = scanner.nextLine();

    if(validator(num)) {
        System.out.println("The calculated value to this account is: " + calculator(num));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Not valid account number!");
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nWould you like to enter another account number? (y/n)");
    String ans = scanner.nextLine();
  
    if (ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N")) {
        newValidator = false;       
    }
}
System.out.println("** Program Exit **");
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Loops can get confusing fast.